# Getting Pointer or Reference to mapped_type from Arbitrary Map

Tags: c++, templates, boost-mpl, boost-ptr-container

**Edit:** I've found and written up a solution to my problem but I've left the question unanswered since my solution may still not be ideal.

I'm writing a small library designed to perform routines on maps of maps, but I'm having trouble designing a set of class templates that will let me get a pointer or reference (depending on the second_type of the map's value_type) to a map's mapped_type, regardless of the type of the map (e.g. std::map, boost::ptr_map).

To elaborate further, I have tabulated some input types and desired output types.

```
Case   Input Type                                   Output Type
 A     std::map<int, std::map<int, int> >           std::map<int, int>&
 B     std::map<int, boost::ptr_map<int, int> >     boost::ptr_map<int, int>&
 C     boost::ptr_map<int, std::map<int, int> >     std::map<int, int>* const
 D     std::map<int, std::map<int, int> >*          std::map<int, int>&
 E     std::map<int, boost::ptr_map<int, int> >*    boost::ptr_map<int, int>&
 F     boost::ptr_map<int, std::map<int, int> >*    std::map<int, int>* const
```

My code passes cases A, B, D and E, but fails on cases C and F. Here is what I have so far.

```
template <class Map>
struct map_utils
{
    template <class K>
    static typename
    boost::remove_pointer<
            typename Map::value_type
    >::type::second_type&
    get(Map& m, const K k)
    {
            return m[k];
    }

    template <class K>
    static typename
    boost::remove_pointer<
            typename Map::value_type
    >::type::second_type&
    get(const Map& m, const K k)
    {
            return const_cast<Map&>(m)[k];
    }
};

template <class Map>
struct map_utils<Map*>
{
    template <class T>
    static typename
    boost::remove_pointer<
            typename Map::value_type
    >::type::second_type&
    get(Map* m, const T t)
    {
            return (*m)[t];
    }

    template <class T>
    static typename
    boost::remove_pointer<
            typename Map::value_type
    >::type::second_type&
    get(const Map* m, const T t)
    {
            return const_cast<Map*>(m)->operator[](t);
    }
};
```

I'm trying to use boost::mpl to do this, and this is what I've cooked up so far, but I get the same error using both versions of the code.

The error.

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::map<int, double>* const&’ from         expression of type     ‘boost::ptr_container_detail::reversible_ptr_container<boost::ptr_container_detail::map_config<std::map<int, double>, std::map<int, void*, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, void*> > >, true>, boost::heap_clone_allocator>::Ty_’
```

The modified specialization of the struct to deal with l-values that are not pointers to maps.

```
template <class K>
    static typename
    boost::mpl::if_<
            boost::is_pointer<
                    typename boost::remove_pointer<
                            typename Map::value_type
                    >::type::second_type
            >,
            typename boost::remove_pointer<
                    typename boost::remove_const<
                            typename Map::value_type
                    >::type
            >::type::second_type,
            typename boost::remove_pointer<
                    typename Map::value_type
            >::type::second_type&
    >::type
    get(Map& m, const K k)
    {
            return m[k];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C and F seems wrong, the mapped type isn't boost::ptr_map. Otherwise it sounds like you could just use full template specialization to decide whether it is an std::map or boost::ptr_map. Something like this:

```
template <class Map>
class Whatever;

template <class K, class V>
class Whatever<std::map<K, V> >
{
    public:
        typedef V& Type;
};

template <class K, class V>
class Whatever<std::map<K, V>* >
{
    public:
        typedef V& Type;
};

template <class K, class V>
class Whatever<boost::ptr_map<K, V> >
{
    public:
        typedef V* const Type;
};

template <class K, class V>
class Whatever<boost::ptr_map<K, V>* >
{
    public:
        typedef V* const Type;
};
```

Comment: Oops, my bad -- it's fixed now.

Comment: Your solution is a lot more elegant than mine -- I hadn't thought to use a template parameters to represent the key and value types.

Comment: In order to accommodate for arbitrary map types, you could change `class Map` to `template <class, class> Map` in the unspecialized version of `class Whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the code the compile successfully and greatly simplified it in the process, by using the mapped_type typedef like so:

```
template <class K>
static typename boost::remove_pointer<
        typename Map::mapped_type
>::type&
get(Map& m, const K k)
{
        return m[k];
}
```

Only the body of the methods needs to be changed in specialized versions of the struct defined in the question above in order to accommodate for pointers to maps as well. If you would like the entire code listing, let me know and I'll dump the entire thing here.